# Overriding HTML & Body font-size when using the 62.5% font-size trick

Tags: html, css, magento

I have developed a web component that has been bundled into a JS SDK that can then be imported into any website. It has been turned into a Woocommerce and Shopify plugin too but Magento seems to be causing a problem with font-sizing.

The web component itself is contained within a shadowDOM so the styling is fine but the culprit for the font issue seems to be the [62.5% font-size trick](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/62-5-percent-font-size-trick/).

**Is there anyway the html and body CSS can be overridden by the widget?**

Here's what the page looks like when the widget loads. As you can see, the "Payment Details", "Previously Used Bank" & "Select Your Bank" text is very small. It is set to .875rem in the widget CSS which renders fine on all other platforms.

[image]

If I remove the following CSS from the Magento site, it then renders fine.

```
html {
   font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
   font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the base font-size of your widget to "medium", and derive your small text as `.875em` from that.